# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am new automation and I am using selenium with python and got stuck.

I am trying to upload the document using `sendkeys` in selenium but getting this error.

```
Error -selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element.
```

Section where i am trying to upload the document ::

[image: Upload document GUI]

Below is the html code:

```html
<spane class="uk-form-file md-btn" style="width:70%;height: 50%">
                                                Upload Document
<input type="file" ngf-select="" id="picture_ids" class="md-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this.files,'picture','document')" name="picture" ng-model="statusUpdate.document" style="width: 100%;" ng-required="true" required="required">
<br>
</spane>
```

and corresponding Selenium code:

```
uploaddoc=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//spane[@class='uk-form-file md-btn']")))
uploaddoc.send_keys("C:/PycharmProjects/Auc/dummy.pdf")
```

Comment: Your HTMl code has syntax error its like `<spane>`. Is there any `<spane/>` tag actual sytax is `<span/>`

Comment: Thanks @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sendKEys to a span element ,

instead you have to use input element.

try using :

```
uploaddoc=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='picture_ids']")))
uploaddoc.send_keys("C:/PycharmProjects/Auc/dummy.pdf")
```

Comment: thanks @PDHide . its working.